# List view height setting along with scroll #Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I have integrated a list view which fetches data from using a web-service  along with other layouts in a content page.
by giving HasUnevenRows="True" property the list view appeared with a 1 row size with scrolling inside so that i was able scroll and view all data inside.
I want to increase the height without losing the scroll.I tried height request to list view and the stacklayout but the scroll is not working.How can i get this done?

thanks in advance

[please click to view Xaml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xwR8.png)

[click to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ec6p.png)

Comment: You mean you want to increase the height of listView and keeping the ListView''s scrolling at the same time?

Comment: yes it needs a height of 4 or 5 rows remaining data will scroll within that height . Can you please take a look at the screen shot in the question please

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Hi